# How to use filter blur with masked element?

Tags: css, svg, mask

I have this svg file:

```
<svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="none" stroke="#000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M17.4634 1.28027L1.17004 17.5619M7.41582 17.5619L17.4634 7.52156M17.4634 13.7628L13.6616 17.5619" stroke-width="2.33" stroke-linecap="round" />
</svg>
```

[image: svg image]

Without any edit to the svg, I want to add `linear-gradient` to it, then `blur`.

```css
span {
  display:block;
  width:19px;
  height:19px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg,red,blue);
  mask-image: url("resize.svg");
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<span> </span>
```

> The file needs to be local so the snippet won't work, but you can try it locally after downloading the svg file.

The result I get from this code:
[image]

What I want instead:

`at 3px blur`

[image]

`at 30px blur`

[image]

1. I can't change the svg file.
2. It needs to be a `linear-gradient` not just a solid color.
3. It must work in `firefox`. Don't mind if it doesn't work in other browsers.
4. It don't need to use mask just a way to add the `linear-gradient` to the img and blur it.
5. The svg file is an external file not inline svg.

Comment: put the <span> inside another element, for example a <p> and blur the <p> instead

Answer (score 0):

it can work if i put the `span` inside another element and apply the `blur` to the parent ( the new element )

```css
span {
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue);
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTkiIGhlaWdodD0iMTkiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxOSAxOSIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjMDAwIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogICAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTE3LjQ2MzQgMS4yODAyN0wxLjE3MDA0IDE3LjU2MTlNNy40MTU4MiAxNy41NjE5TDE3LjQ2MzQgNy41MjE1Nk0xNy40NjM0IDEzLjc2MjhMMTMuNjYxNiAxNy41NjE5IiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjIuMzMiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJyb3VuZCIgLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==');
}

div {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

> the file need to be local so the snippet won't work but you can try it locally after downloading the svg file